# PHP / MS Access DB cannot query anything

Tags: php, ms-access

I am trying to read mdb file using PHP. My phpinfo() shows that PDO_ODBC is present but when I try to do a simple result dump it doesnt return anything? Am I missing anything in the code?

```
<?php
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mdb/Books_be.mdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Books";
$result = $db->query($sql);

print_r($result);
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure maybe the problem is in MDB file. Thats what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is happening?

Comment: Blank screen like nothing is happening. I also tried "Try and Catch".

Comment: It looks like you are using a Mac. Do you have an ODBC driver for Microsoft Access installed on your machine?

Comment: Apparently, display_error was OFF. So the message I get: "Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in..." However PHPINFO says "PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) enabled"

Answer (score 0):

May be variable $dbName is not resolved, try the below and make sure you have

```
<?php
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mdb/Books_be.mdb";
$conn =  "odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=". $dbName . "; Uid=; Pwd=;";
$db = new PDO($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Books";
$result = $db->query($sql);

print_r($result);
?>
```